# How do I concatenate numbers to create a custom date?

Tags: sql-server-2005

Here is what I have tried thus far:

```
select CAST(
    DATEPART(month,getDate())+'-'+
    DATEPART(day,getDate())+'-'+
    2012
    as datetime)
```

I end up with the date: 1905-08-02 00:00:00.0. I was expecting to get today's date. I have rearranged the order and it doesn't seem to change. Can anyone offer as to why it gives me this? For the record, I plan to use other values than 2012 for the year.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `select 10 + '-' + 17` is ... 29 not '12-17'

Answer (score 0):

```
select CAST ('2012'+
             CAST(DATEPART(month,getDate()) as char(2))+
             CAST(DATEPART(day,getDate()) as char(2))
            as datetime)
```

You have to concatenate strings. [Your code is casting the number `2039` to date](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/82655).

If the goal with this little exercise is to be able to change the year of a given date you can do like this instead.

```
declare @NewYear int = 2003

-- with time part
select dateadd(year, @NewYear - year(getdate()), getdate())

-- time part removed
select dateadd(year, @NewYear - year(getdate()), dateadd(day, 0, datediff(day, 0, getdate())))
```

Answer (score 0):

`CAST()` each piece as a varchar first:

```
select 
  cast(
    cast(DATEPART(month,getDate()) as varchar(2))+'-'+
    cast(DATEPART(day,getDate()) as varchar(2))+'-'+
    '2012' as datetime)
```

Answer (score 0):

This code will work, you need to make sure that you are concatenating same data types and use convert with specific DateTime Format:

```
            SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME,
                    CAST(DATEPART(month,getDate()) AS NVARCHAR(50))
                    +'-'+CAST(DATEPART(day,getDate()) AS NVARCHAR(50))
                    +'-2012'
                    ,121)
```